# Creating redistrubutable C/C++ DLLs with VS2012

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, dll

i have a VS2012 C++ project using a vc.mak makefile to build the solution. I build an .exe and a .dll that are both more or less identical (the exe has a main() is about the only difference).

What do I need to do to make it so that these two pieces of code can be run on multiple versions of Windows? I am using Windows 8.1 Pro, and I am of course able to run my exe and use the dll fine. I build a fresh Win8.1 Pro VM, and I discovered trying to run the .exe, it was missing the MSVCR110.dll file, so I copied that over and it ran. My shared library was also able to be used after this.

I copied the entire "install" folder of my project to my coworkers windows 8 box, and the Exe will run, but I can't load the .dll

What do I need to copy over to make my dll run on any Windows box?

Comment: Be aware that there are some constraints if the DLL and the application loading it use different runtime libraries.  For example, you can't pass file descriptors from one to the other, and you can't malloc() a memory block in one and free() it in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Select one of these, you should prefer the third option:

- Some computer games on my computer just have a msvcr*.dll in the directory their executables is present so you can select this approach - just ship that DLL with your executable. You can find that DLL in %WINDIR%\System32 or %WINDIR%\SysWOW64 or "borrow" it from any program which has it copied in its directory and hope it is not modified by an author of the program.
- Another option is to compile that program with a /MT switch instead
  of /MD (or MTd instead of MDd in debug build) but I have no
  experience with makefiles so I can't say how hard is to do it. With
  this approach the run-time library is statically linked to your
  executable - but be ready for the executable to have a higher size.
- A third option is to create an installer which installs your
  application and Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 as
  well - or download and install that redistributable manually.

Comment: thank you - I am pretty sure I would be able to statically link the executable with the exe/dll. I am trying to avoid using an installer in this case because I want my program to run fully contained on a USB drive

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9.aspx) is C++ applications deployment guide from Microsoft, a bit bloated but worth a look.

You can find out DLLs your application depends on with handy [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool. Usually when built with dynamic runtime they are at least msvcr*.dll - Microsoft C Runtime and msvcp*.dll - Microsoft C++ Runtime, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx)  is more detailed list. To deploy Microsoft runtime you can ship official Visual C++ Redistributable installers (VCRedist_x86.exe) with your application. Alternatively for Visual C++ starting from 2010 you can place DLL's at the directory with the executable, for previous versions the process was [a bit more complicated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235291%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

To be able to run applications on Windows XP make sure you select `Platform Toolset` with XP support on `General` tab of project properties (but even then runtime will not start on pre-SP2 systems).